# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: javascript:TagPopup_OpenForm(

Tags: syntax, expression

I am getting this error.It is running perfectly on localhost.

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: javascript:TagPopup_OpenForm("TagPopup_FormContainer1","TagPopup_FormContainerBody1","TagPopup_FormContainerFooter1");

This is my shortcode function in wordpress plugin

```
$siteurl = "'" . home_url() . "'";

$close = 'javascript:TagPopup_HideForm("TagPopup_FormContainer1","TagPopup_FormContainerFooter1");';
$open = 'javascript:TagPopup_OpenForm("TagPopup_FormContainer1","TagPopup_FormContainerBody1","TagPopup_FormContainerFooter1");';

$html = "<a href='" . $open . "'><div class='login-user'>login</div></a>";
$html .= "<div style='display: none;' id='TagPopup_FormContainer1'>";
$html .= "<div id='TagPopup_FormContainerHeader'>";

$html .= '<div id="TagPopup_FormClose"><a href="' . $close . '">' . __('X', 'tag-popup') . '</a></div>';
$html .= '<div id="TagPopup_FormTitle"> ' . __('', 'tag-popup') . wpautop(wp_kses_post($pull_atts['title']));
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<br><hr>';
$html .= '<div id="TagPopup_FormContainerBody1">';

$html .= '<form method="post" action="" name="single_form" id="id_single_Form" onsubmit="return validation_login(this)">';


$html .= '<div id="username-div">';
$html .= '<input name="username" class="username" type="text" id="id_username_login" Placeholder="Username" maxlength="120">';
$html .= '</div>';

$html .= '<div id="password-div">';
$html .= '<input name="password" class="password" type="password" id="id_password_login" Placeholder="Password" maxlength="120">';
$html .= '</div>';

$html .= '<div id="TagPopup_FormLabel_Page">';
$html .= '<input type="submit" name="login" class="login_submit" value="Login" >';

if (!is_home()) {
    $html .= '<a href=' . home_url() . ' style="float:left;#aaffff !important"> < Homepage</a>';
}

$html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '?new_user=1">New user?</a>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '</form>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div style="display: none;" id="TagPopup_FormContainerFooter1"></div>';

return $html;
```

}